# Webservice context path other than web application path

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish

I've created project in netbeans with connection to database, which offers funcionality with Web Service - ws is deployed on Glassfish 4.1.

The problem is that webb application path is

> localhost:8080/C1WSServer

, but web service is accesible thorugh

> localhost:8080/PlayersWS

.

I was lookiing for change it in any configuration file, but there is nothing which could be cause of that strange situation.

In properties -> run parameter 'context path' is /C1WSServer

Where can I look for property, which is resposnisble for it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in @Stateless() annotation before web service class.